# How do I derive the variance of OLS estimators when I have dummy explanatory variables?

Tags: regression, variance, least-squares, binary-data

I know this isn't the smartest question, however I need to derive the variance of the OLS estimators in a Simple Linear Regression Model when the explanatory variable is a dummy one and all the assumptions of the Gauss-Markov theorem are valid.
I know a I should arrive to this:

Var(β1)=σ^2/np(1-p)

but I don't know how to start the proof.

Thank you!

Comment: Your question is unclear, because "dummy variables" are perfectly quantitative.  The variance formulas don't care what the variable means or how it is created.  What, then, would constitute "good input"??

Comment: Does this help answer your question?
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/571881/variance-of-ols-estimator-with-binary-treatment/571883?noredirect=1#comment1055214_571883

Comment: Thank you both for your help, I hope the question is clear now. Sadly I had already checked the question you linked to me, but I am not using matrices, hence I should provide the proof differently.